# Requisição com Ajax sem sucesso

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Olá, estou realizando uma requisição em Ajax, e ocorre um erro em que não é passado o valor do código da linha clicada(em uma tabela) para o Ajax, mas eu tenho um outro exemplo que funciona perfeitamente e esse está com erro.
Eu acredito que o possível erro seja porque quando o usuário clicar no link, na teoria o sistema deveria atualizar na tabela e então mandar para visualização do PDF, mas deve estar dando conflito internamente

Código da Página onde é feita a requisição:

```
<td class="hidden-480">
  <?php $cod_publicacao = $row['cod_publicacao']; ?>
    <a data-id="<?php echo $row['cod_publicacao']; ?>" id="updateVisualization">
      <?php $arquivo = $row['arquivo']; 
        echo"<a href='upload/publicacoes/{$razao_social}/{$tipo}/{$titulo}/{$ano}/{$arquivo}'>
          <i class='ace-icon fa fa-eye bigger-110 hidden-480'></i>&nbsp;Visualizar Arquivo</a>";
?></a>
</td>
```

Código da Requisição:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(document).on('click', '#updateVisualization', function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    var uid = $(this).data('id');   // it will get id of clicked row

    $.ajax({
        url: 'updateVisualization.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'id='+uid,
        dataType: 'html'
    })      
    });

});
```

Página PHP:

```
<?php
    include "conexao.php";
    $pdo= conectar();

    if (isset($_REQUEST['id'])) {
        try{    
        $codigo = intval($_REQUEST['id']);
        $SQL = "UPDATE tbl_publicacao SET status = S WHERE cod_publicacao = ?";
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare( $SQL );
        $stmt->bindValue(1, $cod_publicacao, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute(array(':codigo'=>$codigo));

    }catch(PDOException $e){
        'ERROR :' . $e->getMessage()."<br>";
        'ERROR :' . $e->getCode();
    }}
?>
```

Update:
De acordo com sugestão eu "juntei" os códigos em uma única tag `<a>` entretanto agora ao clicar, nada acontece, nem abre o pdf e nem atualiza no banco, segue o novo código da `<td>`:

```
<td class="hidden-480">
<?php $cod_publicacao = $row['cod_publicacao']; 
$arquivo = $row['arquivo']; 
echo"<a href='upload/publicacoes/{$razao_social}/{$tipo}/{$titulo}/{$ano}/{$arquivo}' id='updateVisualization' data-id='$cod_publicacao'>
<i class='ace-icon fa fa-eye bigger-110 hidden-480'></i>&nbsp;Visualizar Arquivo</a>";
?>
</td>
```

Comment: Você está colocando uma Tag `a` dentro de outra e isso não é permitido. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13052598/creating-anchor-tag-inside-anchor-tag

Comment: Estava com dúvida com isso mas já entendi, muito obrigado, você tem alguma sugestão de como fazer a atualização no banco e abrir o PDF no sistema?

Comment: Primeira coisa que você tem que fazer é juntar esses 2 elementos `<a>` em um único, além disso, qnd você clica ele chega a bater no PHP, dá alguma mensagem de erro?

Comment: Nada, debbugando(acho que é isso) ele nem recebe os valores, ele passa batido, mas obrigado pela ajuda, vou tentar fazer e mostrar os resultados

Comment: Junte os elementos da tag `<a>`, pode ser q ele n esteja nem ido para o PHP por causa disso, caso vc seja isso eu tento te ajudar

Comment: @JefersonAlmeida atualizei os dados

Comment: Funcionou agora?

Comment: Não,agora ao clicar, nada acontece, nem abre o pdf e nem atualiza no banco

Comment: @JefersonAlmeida atualizei o Post

Comment: Substitui seu `data: 'id='+uid` por `data: {id: uid}`, o ideal também era vc debugar o retorno do seu post no php para saber se dá algum erro ou se o id chega corretamente nele

Comment: @JefersonAlmeida agora ele só atualiza e não abre o pdf, mas já é um progresso se vc continuar a ajudar serei grato

Comment: Se já abrisse na outra página não tinha problema, mas não consigo abrir nem com o target="_blank" e se eu clicar em abrir link em nova guia ele já abre normal

Comment: Vou formular uma resposta com tudo aqui

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro você está utilizando uma tag `a` dentro de outra tag `a`, isso não é permito, e com isso deve está gerando seu *HTML* de maneira errada. O ideal é juntar esses 2 elementos em um único.

```
<td class="hidden-480">
<?php $cod_publicacao = $row['cod_publicacao']; 
$arquivo = $row['arquivo']; 
echo"<a href='upload/publicacoes/{$razao_social}/{$tipo}/{$titulo}/{$ano}/{$arquivo}' id='updateVisualization' data-id='$cod_publicacao'>
<i class='ace-icon fa fa-eye bigger-110 hidden-480'></i>&nbsp;Visualizar Arquivo</a>";
?>
</td>
```

Além disso seu ajax está errado, você está passando o data de forma errada, a maneira correta é a que está abaixo:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'updateVisualization.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {id: uid},
    dataType: 'html'
});
```

Além disso como você está sobrescrevendo o click do seu elemento ele não ira mais abrir uma nova página, para contornar isso vamos pegar o valor do `href` e com *js* abrir a página.

```
$(document).on('click', '#updateVisualization', function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    var uid = $(this).data('id');   // it will get id of clicked row
    var href = $(this).attr('href');

    $.ajax({
        url: 'updateVisualization.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {id: uid},
        dataType: 'html'
    }).done(function() {
        window.location.href = href;
    });      
});
```

Você pode verificar que eu peguei o atributo `href` e guardei numa variável e após a finalização do *ajax* eu recarrego a página com esse valor

Comment: Nossa cara, realmente muito muitíssimo obrigado, faz tanto tempo que eu tava procurando ajuda e não tava conseguindo, poxa realmente muito obrigado pela ajuda!